# ¿Cómo gregar un Row en una tabla con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, tablas

Tengo el siguiente código, que su función básica debería de ser el de insertar una nueva fila una vez se le clické en un botón.

```js
function addTable(selft){
     var index=selft.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex;
     var t=document.getElementById("InsertAqui");
     console.log(t);
     var tr=document.createElement("tr");
     var td1=document.createElement("td");
     var td2=document.createElement("td");
     var td3=document.createElement("td");
     var td4=document.createElement("td");

     var t1=document.createTextNode("A");
     var t2=document.createTextNode("B");
     var t3=document.createTextNode("C");
     td2.appendChild(t1);
     td3.appendChild(t2);
     td4.appendChild(t3);
     td1.innerHTML='<button type="button" class="addTable" onclick="addTable(this)">r</button>';
     tr.appendChild(td1);
     tr.appendChild(td2);
     tr.appendChild(td3);
     tr.appendChild(td4);
     console.log(tr);
     t.insertRow(tr,index);
   }
```

```css
table{
     border-collapse: collapse;
   }
   tr{
     border:1px solid #000;
   }
   td{
     border:1px solid #000;
   }
```

```html
<table id="InsertAqui">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>T1</th>
        <th>T2</th>
        <th>T3</th>
        <th>T4</th>
      </tr>  
    </thead>
    <tbody >
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="addTable" onclick="addTable(this)">r</button></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="addTable" onclick="addTable(this)">r</button></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="addTable" onclick="addTable(this)">r</button></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="addTable" onclick="addTable(this)">r</button></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="addTable" onclick="addTable(this)">r</button></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="addTable" onclick="addTable(this)">r</button></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

En la siguiente foto podremos apreciar que efectivamente el `tr` se crea de manera correcta, pero por alguna razón la localiza en el `thead` de la tabla y peor aun no contiene nada:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé como solucionar el problema solo con javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es que estás creando la fila con `document.createElement()` y deberías usar `tabla.appendChild()`, pero, si usas `tabla.insertRow()` se crea la fila en la posición especificada y solo vas agregando columnas:

```js
function addTable(selft){
     var index=selft.parentElement.parentElement.rowIndex;
     var t=document.getElementById("InsertAqui");
     // Al insertar la fila automáticamente se crea <tr />
     var tr=t.insertRow(index);
     var td1=document.createElement("td");
     var td2=document.createElement("td");
     var td3=document.createElement("td");
     var td4=document.createElement("td");

     var t1=document.createTextNode("A");
     var t2=document.createTextNode("B");
     var t3=document.createTextNode("C");
     td2.appendChild(t1);
     td3.appendChild(t2);
     td4.appendChild(t3);
     td1.innerHTML='<button type="button" class="addTable" onclick="addTable(this)">r</button>';
     tr.appendChild(td1);
     tr.appendChild(td2);
     tr.appendChild(td3);
     tr.appendChild(td4);
     console.log(tr);
   }
```

```css
table{
     border-collapse: collapse;
   }
   tr{
     border:1px solid #000;
   }
   td{
     border:1px solid #000;
   }
```

```html
<table id="InsertAqui">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>T1</th>
        <th>T2</th>
        <th>T3</th>
        <th>T4</th>
      </tr>  
    </thead>
    <tbody >
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="addTable" onclick="addTable(this)">r</button></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="addTable" onclick="addTable(this)">r</button></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="addTable" onclick="addTable(this)">r</button></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="addTable" onclick="addTable(this)">r</button></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="addTable" onclick="addTable(this)">r</button></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><button type="button" class="addTable" onclick="addTable(this)">r</button></td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```